# Set label fixed position on mouse enter

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg, geometry

I'm trying to create simple hover effect on circle, using jquery, but I'm stuck in the proccess  of doing this simple task, Problem is, when mouse reaches to the red circle the label which is location of city overlapps circle area, and label moves around circle, i want label to be fixed position on top of red circle.
P.S when i am trying to write description of short named city label overlapping is igonred. for example
`const regionObject = {"philadelphia" : "Philadelphia",}`

```js
$(function(){


   


    $('circle').mouseenter(function(e){

        const circleId = $(this).attr('id');


      
        const regionObject = {
            "philadelphia" : "Philadelphia, sity in pennsylvania",
                    }


        

            var div = $(`<div class="current_region">
            <div class="current_region_box">
            <p>${regionObject[circleId]}</p> 
            </div>
            <div class="region_pointer"></div>
            </div>`)
            .css({
                "display": "block",
                "left": (e.pageX - 40) + 'px',
                "top": (e.pageY - 45) + 'px'
            })
            .appendTo(document.body);

    
    }).mouseout(function(){
    $('body').find('.current_region').remove();
});


    
});
```

```css
.current_region {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .current_region_box {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 1px rgba(18, 40, 112, 0.5);
    padding: 4px 12px;
  }
  
  .current_region_box p {
    font-family: firagolight;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .current_region_box {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 1px rgba(18, 40, 112, 0.5);
    padding: 4px 12px;
  }
  
  .current_region_box p {
    font-family: firagolight;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .region_pointer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    bottom: -9px;
    right: 3px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px grey;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
        <!-- Developer CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./map.css">
        <!-- Jquery-->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="example" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 50px; cursor: pointer; " >
            <svg height="100" width="100">
                <circle id="philadelphia" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"   />
                Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
              </svg>
        </div>


        

<!--Boostrap JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity=" sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="    sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./map.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pure CSS solution, where you utilise ::after pseudoclass which is shown when hovering element. You can position the tooltip by top and left properties.

```css
body { margin: 50px }
#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#circle:after {
  content: "This is tooltip";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  display:none;
  
  /* these are just to make it prettier */
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .7; /* erase this if you dont want it transparent */
}

#circle:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

The value of the tooltip could be taken from any attribute of the circle element, for example title. In the css you would use:
`content: attr(title)`

Answer (score 0):

Using your code you may want to get the center of the circle and use the cx and cy arttributes to position the label.

Also there is a flickering when the mouse touches the label. To fix this you need to add `.current_region{pointer-events:none;}` in CSS

```js
$(function(){


   


    $('circle').mouseenter(function(e){

        const circleId = $(this).attr('id'); 
        const cx = Number($(this).attr('cx'));
        const cy = Number($(this).attr('cy'));

      
        const regionObject = {
            "philadelphia" : "Philadelphia, sity in pennsylvania",
                    }


        

            var div = $(`<div class="current_region">
            <div class="current_region_box">
            <p>${regionObject[circleId]}</p> 
            </div>
            <div class="region_pointer"></div>
            </div>`)
            .css({
                "display": "block",
                "left": (cx + 40) + 'px',
                "top": (cy - 20) + 'px'
            })
            .appendTo(document.body);

    
    }).mouseout(function(){
    $('body').find('.current_region').remove();
});


    
});
```

```css
.current_region {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .current_region_box {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 1px rgba(18, 40, 112, 0.5);
    padding: 4px 12px;
  }
  
  .current_region_box p {
    font-family: firagolight;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .current_region_box {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 1px rgba(18, 40, 112, 0.5);
    padding: 4px 12px;
  }
  
  .current_region_box p {
    font-family: firagolight;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .region_pointer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    bottom: -9px;
    right: 3px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px grey;
  }
  
  .current_region{pointer-events:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
        <!-- Developer CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./map.css">
        <!-- Jquery-->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="example" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 50px; cursor: pointer; " >
            <svg height="100" width="100">
                <circle id="philadelphia" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"   />
                Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
              </svg>
        </div>


        

<!--Boostrap JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity=" sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="    sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./map.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```